# Ajax form submit of file type in tpl file

Tags: codeigniter, smarty

I have application which is in `codeigniter` with smarty template. and I want to submit the form with ajax submit function but the input type is file for image upload and I am using `serialize()` for that but it cant gives me data...

**My .tpl file code is :**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form_submit7" id='form_submit7' class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h4>Logo Uploading</h4>
    <div class="booth-settings">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Upload logo</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="file" name="expo_company_logo" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Logo"><br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" style="margin-top:20px;" id="save-summary" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" value="Upload" />
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**and my ajax function in this file is :**

```
$('#form_submit7').submit(function(){
    var formVars = $(this).serialize();
    **alert(formVars);**

    $.ajax({
        type:     'POST',
        url:     '{/literal}{$site_url}expo/booth_company_logo/{$id}{literal}',
        data:     formVars,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            //alert(data);
            $('#company-pro').html(data);
            $('#radios').css("display","none");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

but in this ajax function in alert part there is not any data comes....

Comment: You haven't showed the whole code - you have {/literal} in your code what means that you used it also before, it's also unclear what's your problem. Please add more defails

Comment: Actually this one is .tpl file of smarty template so before starting jquery/javascript code we have to pass literal so before this code I have passed {literal} tag and I have given only function here so....

Answer (score 0):

i think you've enabled csrf_protection in a config file. if you do so use form_helper's form_open() and form_close() functions when opening and closing your form tag this will include hidden input tag of csrf key inside the form automaticly
example

```
{form_open('',['name'=>'form_submit7','id'=>'form_submit7','class'=>'form-horizontal'])}
    <h4>Logo Uploading</h4>
    <div class="booth-settings">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Upload logo</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="file" name="expo_company_logo" class="form-control" placeholder="Upload Logo"><br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" style="margin-top:20px;" id="save-summary" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" value="Upload" />
         </div>
    </div>
   {form_close()}
```

also do not forget to load form_helper first!